# VMware player installation failed building kernel module 3.11

Tags: kernel, 64-bit, vmware

I'm trying to install VMware player under  Ubuntu 13.04 and my kernel is `3.11.0.2-generic`.

The VMware install failed because it couldn't build kernel module:

The log is:

```
Ago 18 09:27:20.737: app| Log for VMware Workstation pid=9313 version=6.5.5 build=build-328052 option=Release
Ago 18 09:27:20.737: app| Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
Ago 18 09:27:20.737: app| Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/setup-9313.log
Ago 18 09:27:23.829: app| Extracting the sources of the vmmon module.
Ago 18 09:27:23.849: app| Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.11.0-2-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.8
```

How can I solve it?

#### EDIT:

Here is the requested output of `dpkg -l | grep -E 'linux-headers|gcc|build-essential`:

```
ii  build-essential                           11.6ubuntu5    i386         Informational list of build-essential packages
ii  gcc                                       4:4.8.1-2ubuntu2                        i386         GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-4.4                                   4.4.7-2ubuntu2                          i386         GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-4.4-base:i386                         4.4.7-2ubuntu2                          i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-4.8                                   4.8.1-8ubuntu1                          i386         GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-4.8-base:i386                         4.8.1-8ubuntu1                          i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gccxml                                    0.9.0+git20130511-1ubuntu1              i386         XML output extension to GCC
ii  libgcc-4.8-dev:i386                       4.8.1-8ubuntu1                          i386         GCC support library (development files)
ii  libgcc1:i386                              1:4.8.1-8ubuntu1                        i386         GCC support library
ii  linux-headers-3.10.0-4                    3.10.0-4.13                             all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.10.0
ii  linux-headers-3.10.0-4-generic            3.10.0-4.13                             i386         Linux kernel headers for version 3.10.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.11.0-2                    3.11.0-2.5                              all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.11.0
ii  linux-headers-3.11.0-2-generic            3.11.0-2.5                              i386         Linux kernel headers for version 3.11.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                     3.11.0.2.3                              i386         Generic Linux kernel headers
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `dpkg -l | grep -E 'linux-headers|gcc|build-essential'`? That should help show if you have the necessary software installed to build kernel modules.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo -s
sudo apt-get install curl
cd /tmp
curl -O http://pkgbuild.com/git/aur-mirror.git/plain/vmware-patch/vmblock-9.0.2-5.0.2-3.10.patch
curl -O http://pkgbuild.com/git/aur-mirror.git/plain/vmware-patch/vmnet-9.0.2-5.0.2-3.10.patch
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar -xvf vmblock.tar
tar -xvf vmnet.tar
patch -p0 -i /tmp/vmblock-9.0.2-5.0.2-3.10.patch
patch -p0 -i /tmp/vmnet-9.0.2-5.0.2-3.10.patch
tar -cf vmblock.tar vmblock-only
tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
rm -r vmblock-only
rm -r vmnet-only
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

- **Source:** [A post on Ubuntu forums](http://forum.ubuntu-tr.net/index.php?topic=40126.msg476321#msg476321)

Answer (score 2):

If you have your VMWare patched for 3.10, (that's @KemalALKIN 's answer) you only have to do the following:

```
sudo su
cd /tmp
wget https://github.com/willysr/SlackHacks/raw/master/vmware/vmware-3.11/vmblock.3.11.patch
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar -xvf vmblock.tar
cd vmblock-only
patch -p1 < /tmp/vmblock.3.11.patch
cd ..
tar -cvf vmblock.tar vmblock-only/
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

- **Source**: [VMware Player with linux 3.11](http://www.ljasinski.pl/2013/vmware-player-i-kernel-3-11-x/)